# WP - XAML to overlay a grid on a Rectangle

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a `<Rectangle />` on my Windows phone app view which displays the camera feed, and I am trying to figure out the `XAML` code to place a partially transparent image over the feed.

I have the working code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <Rectangle x:Name="_previewRect" 
                   Margin="0" 
                   Height="800" 
                   Width="600" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Tap="OnTapDown">

            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="_previewVideo">
                    <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform  
                            x:Name="_previewTransform" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
                    </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </VideoBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>

       </Rectangle>

    </Grid>
```

Which displays my camera feed perfectly (most of that code is in codebehind of course).

But now I would like to add an image as an overlay. I tried adding:

```
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Background/BackgroundBlurred.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</Grid.Background>
```

both above and below the `<Rectangle />` element, but no such luck.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? It doesn't seem terribly difficult, but I'm just beginning to learn `XAML`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an Image to overlay over the video-feed Rectangle, you must make it a separate control within the "layoutRoot" Grid.  Simply position it directly over the top of your rectangle and give it a higher [Canvas.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980110%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) value:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Rectangle x:Name="_previewRect" 
               Margin="0" 
               Height="800" 
               Width="600" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Tap="OnTapDown"
               Canvas.ZIndex="1">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="_previewVideo">
                <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform  
                        x:Name="_previewTransform" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
                </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </VideoBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

    <Image x:Name="myOverlayImage" Canvas.ZIndex="2">
        <!-- Your overlay is now a sibling of the video-feed Rectangle, but drawn on top of it -->
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I understand your logic here, but my image still isn't showing up. Not even in the ZAML preview. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Make sure your image actually exists by pasting the Image code into an empty Grid.  If it still doesn't show up, then you're not correctly loading the image.  Additionally, try using a filled, plain Rectangle as an overlay, and make sure that appears correctly.  Try a few different combinations to narrow down where your problem is arising.  You can also update your question with the latest code that "doesn't work."

Comment: Got it! the XAML I was referencing the image from was in a child directory, so I had forgot the leading '../' in my path to my image. Works great thanks to you help!